# No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have installed openstack (liberty release). All the services are installed on the VM. Now i am trying to integrate the Ironic service and trying to provision the physical server. 
Nova compute service has configured for baremetal hypervisor and the command "nova hypervisor-stats" shows the correct output.

However, when i am trying to launch the instance from horizon , getting error

> No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available.
>
> somehow , nova compute service is not able to connect to baremetal node OR ironic service.
>   In fact , i have referred the doc :
>   [openstack troubleshoot doc](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ironic/deploy/troubleshooting.html#nova-returns-no-valid-host-was-found-error)

but no luck.

please suggest

Regards

Comment: any suggestions please ?

Comment: Check nova-scheduler.log and look why it is filtering out all hosts. You are most likely hitting some filter.

Comment: can you please elaborate .. ?

Comment: here is what i am getting in nova scheduler log

Comment: here is the log : http://pastebin.com/Df5B4dN6

Comment: from the log it seems that ExactRamFilter returned 0 hosts ..

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when Nova scheduler tries to find a suitable host to instantiate your VM and then could not succeed. Nova scheduler first runs the list of all available hosts through a series of filters to narrow down the list to the best possible hosts that are capable of running that instance.

nova-scheduler.log:

```
... Filter ExactRamFilter returned 0 hosts
... Filtering removed all hosts for the request with reservation ID 'r-mld1goh8' and instance ID '98c49d72-9d8e-4377-bbe0-6dbef187e75a'. Filter results: ['RetryFilter: (start: 3, end: 3)', 'AvailabilityZoneFilter: (start: 3, end: 3)', 'ComputeFilter: (start: 3, end: 3)', 'ComputeCapabilitiesFilter: (start: 3, end: 3)', 'ImagePropertiesFilter: (start: 3, end: 3)', 'ExactRamFilter: (start: 3, end: 0)']
```

ExactRamFilter tries to match a host with the same amount of RAM as the amount of RAM specified in the flavor chosen for the VM. Either create a new flavor or use an existing flavor with exact RAM as the hosts, and you should be able to create the VM successfully (unless you run into some other issues).

Comment: i have created one flavor called baremetal. if i run the command "nova flavor-show baremetal" then in the output, RAM shows 1024 MB as of now .. so you mean to say that, the host which i am provisioning  should have exactly 1024 mb Ram ?? if not, then it will throw such error ?

Comment: Yes, that is how that filter is checking.