# "Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available"+Newton

Tags: openstack, host, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-glance

I have installed openstack (Newton release) on Ubuntu 16.04 (all in one). every service is running well, but when I try to launch an instance, an error occurs:

> Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "test1", the
>   instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: No valid
>   host was found. There are not enough hosts available.].

When I enter:

```
[root@controller-hp ~(keystone_admin)]$ nova-hypervisor-list
+----+---------------------+-------+---------+
| ID | Hypervisor hostname | State | Status  |
+----+---------------------+-------+---------+
| 1  | controller-hp       | up    | enabled |
+----+---------------------+-------+---------+
```

and the output of

```
[root@controller-hp ~(keystone_admin)]$ neutron ext-list
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| alias                     | name                                          |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| default-subnetpools       | Default Subnetpools                           |
| network-ip-availability   | Network IP Availability                       |
| network_availability_zone | Network Availability Zone                     |
| auto-allocated-topology   | Auto Allocated Topology Services              |
| ext-gw-mode               | Neutron L3 Configurable external gateway mode |
| binding                   | Port Binding                                  |
| metering                  | Neutron Metering                              |
| agent                     | agent                                         |
| subnet_allocation         | Subnet Allocation                             |
| l3_agent_scheduler        | L3 Agent Scheduler                            |
| tag                       | Tag support                                   |
| external-net              | Neutron external network                      |
| flavors                   | Neutron Service Flavors                       |
| fwaasrouterinsertion      | Firewall Router insertion                     |
| net-mtu                   | Network MTU                                   |
| availability_zone         | Availability Zone                             |
| quotas                    | Quota management support                      |
| l3-ha                     | HA Router extension                           |
| provider                  | Provider Network                              |
| multi-provider            | Multi Provider Network                        |
| address-scope             | Address scope                                 |
| extraroute                | Neutron Extra Route                           |
| shared_pools              | Shared pools for LBaaSv2                      |
| subnet-service-types      | Subnet service types                          |
| standard-attr-timestamp   | Resource timestamps                           |
| fwaas                     | Firewall service                              |
| service-type              | Neutron Service Type Management               |
| lb_network_vip            | Create loadbalancer with network_id           |
| l3-flavors                | Router Flavor Extension                       |
| port-security             | Port Security                                 |
| hm_max_retries_down       | Add a fall threshold to health monitor        |
| extra_dhcp_opt            | Neutron Extra DHCP opts                       |
| standard-attr-revisions   | Resource revision numbers                     |
| lbaasv2                   | LoadBalancing service v2                      |
| pagination                | Pagination support                            |
| sorting                   | Sorting support                               |
| lbaas_agent_schedulerv2   | Loadbalancer Agent Scheduler V2               |
| security-group            | security-group                                |
| dhcp_agent_scheduler      | DHCP Agent Scheduler                          |
| router_availability_zone  | Router Availability Zone                      |
| lb-graph                  | Load Balancer Graph                           |
| rbac-policies             | RBAC Policies                                 |
| l7                        | L7 capabilities for LBaaSv2                   |
| standard-attr-description | standard-attr-description                     |
| router                    | Neutron L3 Router                             |
| allowed-address-pairs     | Allowed Address Pairs                         |
| project-id                | project_id field enabled                      |
| dvr                       | Distributed Virtual Router                    |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

My nova.conf file is here:

https://paste.debian.net/1005278/

‌‌By using this [guide](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-rdo/launch-instance-networks-provider.html), My network configuration is:

Network Overview

```
Name
    physical01
ID
    212248e9-71ff-4015-8fec-54567f38e92f
Project ID
    43605ff65d2a40d19073e7268fd5d124
Status
    Active
Admin State
    UP
Shared
    Yes
External Network
    Yes
MTU
    1500
Provider Network
    Network Type: flat
    Physical Network: physical01
    Segmentation ID: -
```

and:

```
[root@controller-hp ~(keystone_admin)]$ neutron net-list
+--------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------+
| id                             | name       | subnets                        |
+--------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------+
| 212248e9-71ff-4015-8fec-       | physical01 | ee667189-bb7c-4861-81a0-2735d0 |
| 54567f38e92f                   |            | 1c2011 10.1.79.0/24            |
+--------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------+
```

I use a large flavor for `Cirros 0.3.4 64 bits`  image that is shows the problem doesn't relevant to resource.

that's the output of "`tailf /var/log/neutron/neutron-*.log`"

http://paste.openstack.org/show/648396/

These are my plugins configure:

[ml2](http://paste.openstack.org/show/648401/)

[Linux Bridge Agent](http://paste.openstack.org/show/648403/)

[openvswitch](http://paste.openstack.org/show/648404/)

[DHCP agent](http://paste.openstack.org/show/648410/)

[L3 agent](http://paste.openstack.org/show/648413/)

I'd read these topics, but they couldn't solve my problem:

[OpenStack Newton Installation(using packstack) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165405/openstack-newton-installationusing-packstack-error)

[No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130136/no-valid-host-was-found-there-are-not-enough-hosts-available)

...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/92701/no-valid-host-was-found-there-are-not-enough-hosts-available/

Comment: @Lucas yes, but it  didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may get clues from the following logs on compute nodes:
/var/log/nova/nova-scheduler.log
/var/log/neutron/neutron-*.log

Comment: It's about my network configuration problem. May I have your email address for asking some question about configuring it? I get confused.

Comment: Apparently looks like the error "Could not load neutron.agent.linux.interface.BridgeInterfaceDriver" could be ignored. 

The post here talks about the same. 

https://www.funkypenguin.co.nz/note/openstack-neutron-could-not-load-interfacedriver-warnings-are-harmless/

Is there is a possibility that some things else is causing this issue? 

Can you paste the complete neutron and nova log file if that is ok?

Comment: I think maybe my network configuration may has problem.. yes of course: thats my nova-* log : http://paste.openstack.org/show/649413/ and this is my neutron-* log: http://paste.openstack.org/show/649417/